# OutOfMemoryError Bitmap to Base64 string

Tags: java, android, base64, out-of-memory

I have an error in Android, can someone help me?

my Activity code :

```
    profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    Connect.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},CODE_GALLERY_REQUEST
            );
        }

    });



}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode==CODE_GALLERY_REQUEST){
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image"),CODE_GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this," Pour créer une  photo de profil merci de nous donner la permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        return;
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==CODE_GALLERY_REQUEST&&resultCode==RESULT_OK&&data!=null){

        Uri filePath=data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePath);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imagedata = imageToString(bitmap);
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void updateLabel() {
    String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.FRANCE);

    naissance.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}



public void inscription(View view){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Chargement...");
    progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_inscription,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if(response.equals("SUCCES")){
                       // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Connexion.class);

                      //  startActivity(intent);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(Connect.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"verifier votre connexion internet et réessayer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("image",imagedata);
            params.put("pseudo",pseudo.getText().toString());
            params.put("nom",nom.getText().toString());
            params.put("prenom",prenom.getText().toString());
            params.put("password",password.getText().toString());
            params.put("email",email.getText().toString());
            params.put("naissance",naissance.getText().toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
    String encoded = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
return encoded;
}
 }
```

Error Stack:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: tn.events.events, PID: 16587
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24551844 byte allocation with 8376560 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
                      at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:88)
                      at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromBytes(StringFactory.java:65)
                      at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
                      at tn.events.events.Connect.imageToString(Connect.java:195)
                      at tn.events.events.Connect.onActivityResult(Connect.java:129)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6674)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4009)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4056)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:196)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1588)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

Comment: How come you don't know what is required here? Exception says it all. :-/

Comment: The cause is self-evident from your code and the stacktrace.  You are attempting to create a string that is too big for memory.  The solutions:  1) don't allow big images, 2) increase the heap size, or 3) figure out a way to POST the request without converting the image to in-memory base64 string (e.g. stream it!)